# Rotation/Translation beween 2 Maps?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

I have 2 maps, a location value is represented $(x,y)$ on Map1 and $(X,Y)$ on Map2.

I want to know how much rotation and translation is needed to match Map1 and Map2.

i.e.
I need to calculate $\theta, a,b$ in the following equation.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ 1\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & a \\
\sin\theta &\cos\theta & b \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have 3 pairs of $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$.
But they are experimental observed values, thus containing some errors.
How can I specify above $\theta, a,b$ ?

Sincerely,
thank you for your time.

Comment: You might get more response on a mathematics site.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you tell me somewhere if you have any suggested site ?

Comment: Many, many versions of this question have been asked and answered on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).  With only three pairs, statistics can't help you much, because you haven't any information to estimate the errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather simple technique, [Procrustes analysis,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis) which does just that. You may use the link provided or you will find a description in some Multivariate Analysis books (e.g., Krzanowski, W.J. *Principles of Multivariate Analysis*, Oxford Scientific Press).

Comment: Could you explain how this would apply when there are just three pairs of (x,y) data?

Comment: @whuber, checking the formulae involved I see no problems (no inverses of rank defficient matrices, or such). I agree that I would  not place great confidence in any results from such a small body of information, if that is your point: but perhaps the person asking may gather some more data.

Comment: That's correct.  But as far as I am aware, Procrustes analysis takes no heed of the nature of errors in either set of coordinates.  I see this as being analogous to the difference between ordinary regression and errors-in-variables regression.

Comment: Yes, that is true; but the person asking did not mention that this could be a problem. On the other hand, while Procrustes analysis makes no allowance for e.g. different variances of the errors in either map, it does account for changes in scale, as long as the space is isotropic. One matches one map to the other by means of a shift plus a rotation plus (optionally) an expansion (or stretching) of the scale (by means of a "dilation coefficient").